# Morels growing in planter pot: leave them alone, or extirpate?

Tags: fungus

We have a planter with a tomato plant and a bell pepper (capsicum) plant. A few months ago, during wet weather, many morels (specifically what appears to be *Morchella rufobrunnea*) started to appear next to the plants. Some research shows that the presence of this *Morchella* is quite common in our area and grows readily from wood chips in moist conditions.

While I'm not too upset by their presence (indeed they appear to be edible!), I'm wondering whether for the sake of the plants it's better to leave the fungi in, or to remove their visible parts.

Fungi seem to break down decomposing organic matter into components that the plants can perhaps use, but I want to be sure that 1) the fungi don't house other creatures that might harm the plants, or 2) that the fungi may affect the growth of the plants themselves.

[image]

Comment: I would eat them, if I were you. Yummy if cooked properly.

Comment: Indeed, they smell kind of delicious. Any harm to the plants leaving them in the planter, though?

Comment: I can't see any harm with them in the planter - they shouldn't affect them at all (but as Bamboo noted, an indoor planter would be a different matter - if you didn't eat them first).

Comment: Morels normally only fruit for a couple weeks in spring when the oaks are starting to get leaves  , so not a persistent "problem".

Answer (score 1):

Their presence won't harm the plants in the container, but as these are fruiting bodies, at some point they will eject spores around  and about - if the planter  is indoors, you might  not want those floating  in the air, though they won't cause you any problems either. You might want to remove them for aesthetic reasons, but it's  not essential.